# Decrementing for loop in coffeescript

Tags: loops, for-loop, coffeescript, decrement

I know how to do a incrementing for loop in coffeescript such as:

Coffeescript:

```
for some in something
```

Generated Javascript:

```
for (_i = 0, _len = something.length; _i < _len; _i++)
```

How do I create a decrementing for loop similar to this in Coffeescript?

```
for (var i = something.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**EDIT: As of CoffeeScript 1.5 `by -1` syntax is supported.**

First, you should familiarize yourself with the `by` keyword, which lets you specify a step. Second, you have to understand that the CoffeeScript compiler takes a very naïve approach to loop endpoints (see [issue 1187](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1187), which Blender linked to), which means that

```
for some in something by -1 # don't do this!!!
```

will result in an infinite loop—it starts at index 0, increments the index by -1, and then waits until the index hits `something.length`. Sigh.

So you need to use the range loop syntax instead, which lets you specify those endpoints yourself—but also means you have to grab the loop items yourself:

```
for i in [something.length - 1..0] by -1
  some = something[i]
```

Obviously that's pretty messy. So you should strongly consider iterating over `something.reverse()` instead. Just remember that `reverse()` modifies the array that you call it on! If you want to preserve an array but iterate over it backwards, you should copy it:

```
for some in something.slice(0).reverse()
```

Comment: I think you don't even need the `-1`. `for i in [sth.length-1..0]` works fine

Comment: @RicardoTomasi You're correct that it will work without the `by -1`, but it's less efficient—look at the compiled output for both. From the compiler's perspective, `something.length` is potentially negative, so the step is potentially either `1` or `-1`.

Comment: @RicardoTomasi You need the `by -1 ` if `sth` is an empty array. Otherwise the loop would run two times more than expected (zero times). Once for `-1` and once for `0`.

Comment: @Robert good catch. `for i in [sth.length-1...-1]` "fixes" that :D

Comment: Note that `array[..]` is shorthand for `array.slice(0)`.

Comment: @davidchambers True, as of CoffeeScript 1.3.1.

Answer (score 38):

As of coffee-script [1.5.0](http://coffeescript.org/#changelog) this is supported:

```
for item in list by -1
  console.log item
```

This will translate into

```
var item, _i;
for (_i = list.length - 1; _i >= 0; _i += -1) {
  item = list[_i];
  console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: You can also use the `element, index` syntax with this like:
`console.log "#{item.toString()} at index #{index}" for item, index in list by -1`

Answer (score 2):

A different take just for the record:

```
i = something.length
while item = something[--i]
  #use item
```

(will break on falsy values)

Comment: this one doesn't break when used over empty arrays

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be an elegant way to loop in reverse.

I checked the GitHub ticket regarding this, but it has been closed: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1187

The syntax used to be:

```
for some in something by -1
```

But it has been removed in recent versions.
EDIT: it works now (for 1.6.2 @time of edit)

Answer (score 0):

Idiomatic way (from [docs](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#loops)) along the lines of:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for n in (num for num in [lst.length-1..0])
  alert lst[n]
```

*(Edited after @Trevor's note)*

**Edit:**

Although, if performance is critical, this equivalent but maybe less aesthetic snippet will generate less resulting javascript:

```
lst = [1,2,3]
i = lst.length
alert lst[i] while i--
```

Comment: Umm, this only works if `lst` is `[1,2,3]`. If you try, say, `lst = ['a','b','c']`, the output will still be `3`, `2`, `1`.

Answer (score 0):

For a decrementing, index-based for loops, you can use:

```
for i in [0...something.length].reverse()
```

This removes the messiness @TrevorBurnham mentioned is an issue with specifying endpoints yourself.

When `something.length` is `0`, this is equivalent to

```
for i in []
```